# cannot remove blank option from angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is the select box

```
<form name="permissionForm" novalidate>
    <select ng-model="permissionForm.homePostPermission" name="permissionHomePage" ng-options="permission.name for permission in permissions" required>
    </select>
    <div ng-show="permissionFormErrorShowTag">
        <div ng-show="permissionForm.permissionHomePage.$error.required">Required</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And this is the controller code

```
//setting the values of permission
$scope.permissions = [{'name':'Public','value':'1'},{'name':'Friend','value':'2'},{'name':'Only me','value':'3'}];
$scope.permissionForm = {};
$scope.permissionForm.homePostPermission = $scope.permissions[0].value;
```

The blank option is still shown in the select options.Cannot discard it.Please help me.

Have added this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/MTfRD/2957/

Thank you for your time

Comment: @tushar please i have added a working fiddle.

Comment: it should be `$scope.permissionForm.homePostPermission = $scope.permissions[0]` but it ignore it . declaring the form in the html reinit the value of permissionForm i don't know why. look at this 

http://plnkr.co/edit/9wCmBwiyGV5zRBM3Ez8z?p=preview

Comment: @AlainIb what should i do?

Comment: Your actual problem is that you use `<form name="permissionForm">` and then the same scope variable name `$scope.permissionForm`.  If you have a look at [this part in the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#usage). > `Name of the form. If specified, the form controller will be published into related scope, under this name.` You must rename one of them!

Comment: @ippi this was the problem.Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. change form name.and also init model with object.

```js
var app = angular.module("app",  []);

app.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.permissions = [{'name':'Public','value':'1'},{'name':'Friend','value':'2'},{'name':'Only me','value':'3'}];
    $scope.permissionForm = {};
    $scope.permissionForm.homePostPermission = $scope.permissions[0];

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.2/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
     <form name="form" novalidate>
    <select ng-model="permissionForm.homePostPermission"  ng-options="permission.name for permission in permissions" required>
    </select>
   
</form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add track by **permision.value** in ng-options as follows:

```
 <select class="form-control" ng-model="permissionForm.homePostPermission"   name="permissionHomePage" ng-options="permission.name for permission in permissions track by permision.value" required=""></select>
```

You are done! Best of luck :)

**Plunker Output:**

http://plnkr.co/edit/XnvfIFkuzu0opanIcMES?p=preview

Comment: it is not working fully.As i have set the first option which will be selected.`$scope.permissionForm.homePostPermission = $scope.permissions[0]`.But the last option is being selected.